# Is scaling to absolute zero a bad way to hide an element?

Tags: scale

Usually if I'm going to scale a polygon (for duplifacing) or a whole *Object* in order to reveal it smoothly during animation, I set **0** value as a float **0.0001**.

It is still invisible for the eyes but annoying to setup in keyframes/drivers.

Should I continue to limit it every time or I can put a **real 0** without a doubt and won't get any problems with rendering or exporting?

Comment: What have your tests told you about rendering or exporting for you current methond?

Comment: Interested to hear your results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, you are fine to use zero for a scaling factor for objects - those scaled meshes will simply be reduced down to a point, but with no actual loss of geometry; increasing the scale factor again will restore your mesh and while scaled down to a point will not be visible in your render.

However, for scaling faces, you *will lose geometry* by scaling down to zero in Edit mode - since all vertices will exist at the exact same point so there is nothing to 'scale back up'. Note though, that in this situation, even scaling down to a *very small* scale (but not zero) may introduce rounding issues with the vertices in your mesh when you scale back up again. The exception to this is if you are scaling the faces using a modifier (such as an Armature or Deform modifier) since the underlying geometry is not actually affected and so can be restored without distortion.

Comment: Would a  point shapekey  be another exception?

Comment: @batFINGER A shapekey would be OK as it’s effectively a deform modifier - so the underlying geometry change can be undone and the original geometry restored (so the acale to zero can be undone).

Comment: Interesting thing that duplifaces' `inherit scale` is limited to *0.001*